# htmlanchor string URL dropping leading '..'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to write a string link to an HtmlAnchor tag.  The url has two leading '..' but when I look at the source, the leading '..' are being dropped.  This is the write process:

```
string PageNumStr = "../PDFView/PDFView.aspx?pgID=" + page + "&adID=" + 
    PageID + "&ref=50";
```

How do I ensure that the leading '..' are not dropped?

Comment: You should also show how you are assigning it to the src attribute of the anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this ASP.NET? By "source", do you mean HTML source in the browser? Do you have a `<base href>` tag on the page? And how does the string get onto the page (you only show it being assigned to a variable).

It's hard to tell what you are seeing without some context. Make sure you aren't looking at a resolved URL when you say the ".." is removed. What are the before and after URLs?

Comment: Yes, yes and no, this is a link to an app which is in the directory above and that resolves the link.  It should appear in the source as written with the leading '..' which as I stated are dropped.